# Keyboard shortcut to decrease size of window?

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, shortcut, window-manager, ergonomics

I am trying to decrease the size of a given window, vertically. I have to manually hover over the top edge of the window, wait for the double arrow to show up, then pull down.

Very annoying and time-consuming.

Is there a shortcut to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: A similar question was asked on SuperUser: [What keyboard shortcuts move, resize, and maximize windows under Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x)